# Where is the Javascript attribute window._wpCustomHeaderSettings defined?

Tags: javascript, custom-header, video-header

I'm trying to modify the behaviour of the Javascript function defined in wp-includes/js/wp-custom-header.js, to change the minimum windows height to display a video header.
For this, I need to modify the attribute `window._wpCustomHeaderSettings.minHeight`
At the time that my script runs, `window._wpCustomHeaderSettings` is not defined yet, so I create it with a `window._wpCustomHeaderSettings = window._wpCustomHeaderSettings || {}`, then set the attribute `minHeight` to a value of 0.

However, after the page is loaded, if I use the browser console to display this attribute, I see that it has the default value of 500.

So I tried to see where this value was defined to understand what I was doing wrong, but I couldn't, despite all my `grep`s through Wordpress source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's defined via `wp_localize_script()` that's called by [`the_custom_header_markup()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_custom_header_markup/):

```php
wp_localize_script( 'wp-custom-header', '_wpCustomHeaderSettings', get_header_video_settings() );
```

So if you want to override the values/settings using JavaScript, then you can hook to `wp_print_footer_scripts` and add your script like so:

```php
add_action( 'wp_print_footer_scripts', function(){
    if ( wp_script_is( 'wp-custom-header' ) ) :
    ?>
        <script>
        if ( window._wpCustomHeaderSettings ) {
            _wpCustomHeaderSettings.minHeight = 0;
        }
        </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}, 11 );
```

But the variable name starts with `_` which normally indicates a private variable that should never be "touched" (other than for reading its values), so I suggest you to use the [`header_video_settings`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/header_video_settings/) filter instead to override the default `minHeight` (or any setting's) value:

```php
add_filter( 'header_video_settings', function( $settings ){
    $settings['minHeight'] = 0;
    return $settings;
} );
```

Comment: This is working perfectly, thank you very much the clarity of your answer.